# TypeError: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment is not a function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

in my cloud functions, I'm trying to **increment a value by 1**, using a batched write. This is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
try { admin.initializeApp() } catch (e) { }

const db = admin.firestore()

export const createInteraction = functions.https.onCall(async (data: any, context: any) => {
  if (context && context.auth) {
    const interactionType = data.interactionType
    const referencedContent = data.referencedContent
    const currentUser = context.auth.token.uid

    if (typeof interactionType === "string" && ["like", "reblog"].includes(interactionType) && typeof referencedContent === "string") {
      try {
        const batch = db.batch()
        const interactionRef = db.collection("ugc").doc()

        batch.set(interactionRef, { cid: interactionRef.id, referencedContent: referencedContent, type: interactionType, uid: currentUser, timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP });

        const nativeContentRef = db.collection("ugc").doc(referencedContent)
        const increment = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)

        if (interactionType === "like")
          batch.update(nativeContentRef, { 'likes': increment })
        else
          batch.update(nativeContentRef, { 'reblogs': increment })

        await batch.commit()
        return { code: 200, success: true, message: "Successfully created the interaction!" }

      } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occured trying to create a new interaction:", error)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', "An error happened creating the interaction!")  
      }
    } else { return { code: 400, success: false, message: "The data attached to this request is invalid. We could not process it." }}
  } else {
    return { code: 401, success: false, message: 'The request was unauthenticated. We could not process it.'}
  }
})
```

**This is the error I get:**

> An error occured trying to create a new interaction:
>   TypeError: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment is not a function
>       at exports.createInteraction.functions.https.onCall (/srv/lib/interactions.js:21:62)
>       at func (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:320:32)
>       at 
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

I really don't know where the error is - all the approaches recommended in other SO Questions with the same error do not work.

I would be extremely thankful for any help I could get.

Comment: I'm curious why you override the types of `data` and `context` with `any`.  They should have their own very well-defined TypeScript types by default and these should help your IDE with autocomplete.

Comment: Also, you should not try to catch an error here. If init fails, you will just defer another error to a future call to the admin SDK, which will be more difficult to diagnose.  Just let it fail normally with a helpful error message in the log: `try { admin.initializeApp() } catch (e) { }`

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your help. What should be the right type of data/context? If I remove any, I'm getting an error `Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.` Also, I've split up my code into multiple files, and as far as I know, there must be only one call to initializeApp()? That's why I put the try/catch there.

Comment: Make sure your dependencies are all up to date, and you're using the latest version of TypeScript.  I don't know what causes that error about "any", but I've never seen it myself.  My projects always are able to correctly infer the type from the TypeScript bindings provided by firebase-functions without having to specify any type information myself.

Comment: @DougStevenson my firebase packages are all up to date, so is typescript?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  It sounds like something is wrong in your project. Try rebuilding it from scratch.  The types should be inferred, and you should be able to use `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` exactly like that after importing firebase-admin.

Comment: @linus_hologram Instead of using `try { admin.initializeApp() } catch (e) { }`, use `if (!admin.apps.length) { admin.initializeApp() }`. Unless your app makes use of more than one named application at a time, this is sufficient to test if the Admin SDK has already been initialized and won't sink any errors thrown by `initializeApp` if it fails for other reasons.

Comment: Out of curiosity as this is a type error, what do you get when you run `typeof admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment`?

Comment: @samthecodingman I'm sorry - just as Doug Stevenson called it, my entire project bricked as I tried to update TypeScript :-/ I'm afraid I can't tell you what I get there. Probably have to setup a brand new CloudFunctions folder 

Comment: @linus_hologram Have had that problem before - I simply stopped using Typescript :D